# SAML Response string contains caret ^ symbol which is invalid base64 string

Tags: curl, encoding, saml, saml-2.0, url-encoding

I am using below code to get saml assertion

```
        if (rawSamlData.Contains("%"))
        {

            rawSamlData = System.Net.WebUtility.UrlDecode(rawSamlData);
        }

        // read the base64 encoded bytes
        byte[] samlData = Convert.FromBase64String(rawSamlData);

        // read back into a UTF string
        string samlAssertion = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(samlData);
```

Some of the clients sends saml response which contains invalid base64 character, specifically % is wrapped by ^, so %0D is ^%^0D and %0A is ^%^0A.
When I try to Convert.FromBase64String, it throws

```
The input is not a valid Base-64 string as it contains a non-base 64 character, more than two padding characters, or an illegal character among the padding characters
```

I am struggling to understand why % is wrapped by ^ in the saml response string.
Any help on this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Unclear what you’re asking here. `%0D` would not be valid base64 on its own already, even without any circumflexes.

Comment: @CBroe, any raw saml string before UrlDecode, it would contain encoded escape characters such as %0D, however the saml response I get from many clients have ^ wrapped around % symbol which does not let it decode properly.

Comment: So you don't have an actual base64 encoding problem, you have one on the layer above that. If the SAML documentation doesn't say that this is somehow valid data and how to handle it - then you should answer those clients with an error maybe.

Comment: @CBroe, yes absolutely. the saml response that comes from client has invalid characters. Doing the same. Hope to get reply from clients about their encoding patterns.